# Getting applications information installed on the device

Tags: blackberry

I want to get the information of the installed applications on the device by code. Like for example when entering the settings in the device then applications you can see all the applications installed ... well I want to get that by code... how to do that?

Any idea about that topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the API documentation on [CodeModuleManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/CodeModuleManager.html).

And, part of the way StackOverflow works is that when you get an answer that solves your problem you should accept that answer. This is how you repay people for taking the time to help you out. You are a new user, and not too many questions yet, but if you get to far ahead of yourself without accepting answers people may stop answering them.